# Django and Folium integration

Tags: python, django, maps, folium

Django newbie here: my aim is to integrate Folium to an html page. so what I have at the moment:

**polls/views.py**

```
def show_map(request):  
    #creation of map comes here + business logic
    m = folium.Map([51.5, -0.25], zoom_start=10)
    test = folium.Html('<b>Hello world</b>', script=True)
    popup = folium.Popup(test, max_width=2650)
    folium.RegularPolygonMarker(location=[51.5, -0.25], popup=popup).add_to(m)

    context = {'my_map': m}

    return render(request, 'polls/show_folium_map.html', context)
```

**polls/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [   
       path('show_my_map', views.show_map, name='show_map'),
```

]

and **show_folium_map.html**

```
 <h1>map result comes here</h1>
 {{ my_map }}
```

problem is that I get the 'to_string' value of the map (I promise you I saw that coming). So how can I integrate the map in such way that I can actually see the map and also define the size?

[image]

Comment: check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/231845) out!

Comment: @Lemayzeur thanks! you will note from my code that I actually took it from the post you mentioned. Problem is that it does m.save('osm.html') and while I can save it to an html and reference it from another file - I'm not sure if this doesn't present a problem with multiple users. Any ideas if this consider 'safe'. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

In order to really include folium into custom django template you have to render your figure first before adding it to context (This will recursivly load all parts of the map into the figure). Afterwards in your template, you have to access header, html and script parts of figure seperatly by calling their render function. Additionally, those parts have to marked as "safe" by django template tag in order to allow html insertion. See example below.

**Example:**

views.py:

```py
import folium

from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class FoliumView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "folium_app/map.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        figure = folium.Figure()
        m = folium.Map(
            location=[45.372, -121.6972],
            zoom_start=12,
            tiles='Stamen Terrain'
        )
        m.add_to(figure)

        folium.Marker(
            location=[45.3288, -121.6625],
            popup='Mt. Hood Meadows',
            icon=folium.Icon(icon='cloud')
        ).add_to(m)

        folium.Marker(
            location=[45.3311, -121.7113],
            popup='Timberline Lodge',
            icon=folium.Icon(color='green')
        ).add_to(m)

        folium.Marker(
            location=[45.3300, -121.6823],
            popup='Some Other Location',
            icon=folium.Icon(color='red', icon='info-sign')
        ).add_to(m)
        figure.render()
        return {"map": figure}
```

templates/folium_app/map.html:

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    {{map.header.render|safe}}
</head>
<body>
  <div><h1>Here comes my folium map:</h1></div>
  {{map.html.render|safe}}
  <script>
    {{map.script.render|safe}}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing displays when I use this.  It's not invisible or set to not display, there's just nothing there.

Comment: @Alexej Magura: Something in the browser console? Can you see header, content and script in page source? Can you share a link to your code?

Comment: Instead of using figure, change to `m = m._repr_html_()`, return `"map": m`, and in html: `{{map|safe}}`.

Answer (score 8):

You can try the below way. I also had faced the same issue and it worked great for me.

#### views.py

```
def show_map(request):  
    #creation of map comes here + business logic
    m = folium.Map([51.5, -0.25], zoom_start=10)
    test = folium.Html('<b>Hello world</b>', script=True)
    popup = folium.Popup(test, max_width=2650)
    folium.RegularPolygonMarker(location=[51.5, -0.25], popup=popup).add_to(m)
    m=m._repr_html_() #updated
    context = {'my_map': m}

    return render(request, 'polls/show_folium_map.html', context)
```

#### show_folium_map.html

```
{{ my_map|safe }}
```

Comment: Hello, your answer works great, but I can see one problem. In my project I am taking data from Postgres, and I am adding clusters, popups. And if the query is big, map renders 2-3 seconds, and while waiting for the map I can see a message in map place: "'Make this Notebook Trusted to load map: File -> Trust Notebook". Does anyone know why that happens?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the html as a string by triggering the rendering on the (internal) parent of `Map`:

```
m = folium.Map()
html: str = m.get_root().render()
```

Note that this returns a full html page, so you may need to put it in an iframe.

Alternatively, you can render the head, body and script parts separately. That way you can put each part on your page where it belongs and you don't need an iframe:

```
m = folium.Map()
html_head: str = m.get_root().header.render()
html_body: str = m.get_root().html.render()
html_script: str = m.get_root().script.render()
```