# Error when trying to render Folium map on Django Server

Tags: python, django, dictionary, render, folium

view.py

```
map = folium.Map(location=[df['latitude'].mean(), 
df['longitude'].mean()],tiles="cartodbpositron",zoom_start=12)

map.save("map.html")

context = {'my_map': map}

return render(request, 'my_map.html', context)
```

my_map.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ my_map }}
</body>
```

browser result:

```
folium.folium.Map object at 0x7f49d85662b0
```

im not sure how to approach getting the html/js to work on the browser after the user has submitted their input via the previous html form...
I have seemed to look everywhere and there are a lot of similar problems with solutions but I could not get any to work!

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have enough rep to post plain images!

Comment: You shouldn't be posting images of code at all!

Comment: #virtualmachinethings

Comment: That's better. Now post more of the view so that we can see what `map` is.

Comment: I have updated some context of what map is. Map works fine if I am just simply run the html file however when its in the context of the django server and being parsed to be rendered it's having some problems.

Answer (score 5):

This response is here to increase the google coverage for others who, like me, also experienced this problem when trying to render a Folium map within a Django template.

## Your Code

Please see the comments inside each code block for how to render the map as expected.

### views.py

```py
map = folium.Map(location=[df['latitude'].mean(), 
df['longitude'].mean()],tiles="cartodbpositron",zoom_start=12)

map.save("map.html")

# {'my_map': map} will output the object, which is what you are seeing
# to rectify this we need to turn it into an iframe which 
# the template can then render.
context = {'my_map': map} # change to {'my_map': map._repr_html_()}

return render(request, 'my_map.html', context)
```

### Template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
# after making the change in our views.py this will return the html but
# the template will not render it as expected because it is being escaped.
# You must declare it 'safe' before it will be rendered correctly.
{{ my_map }} # change to {{ my_map | safe }}
</body>
```

For more information see the Folium doc page [here](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/flask.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411707/folium-map-not-displaying-in-django-webpage) SO post.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello, your answer works great, but I can see one problem. In my project I am taking data from Postgres, and I am adding clusters, popups. And if the query is big, map renders 2-3 seconds, and while waiting for the map I can see a message in map place: "Make this Notebook Trusted to load map: File -> Trust Notebook". Does anyone know why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

[Map](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.ht) objects have a render `method` which render its html representation.

You can try directly:

```
<body>
{{ my_map.render }}
</body>
```

Or you can use the `Map.render` method to implement a custom inclusion tag, that way you can pass arguments to the render method. See this for reading more about [inclusion and custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/).

```
# The template tag.
for django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.inclusion_tag
def render_map(map_object, **kwargs):
    return map_object.render(**kwargs)
```

In your template:

```
<body>
{% render_map my_map some_arg1=arg1  some_arg2=arg2 %}
</body>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I tried the direct approach, instead of it printing the folium map object, it now prints 'None' on the page! Thanks for the information on inclusion and custom tags too :)

Comment: Well if it prints `None` that's a problem with the map object (a different problem). I'm glad to help.