# How to display a map in browser using python and DJANGO API?

Tags: python, html, django, api, maps

I am getting difficulty while displaying my map on a web browser. I am using DJANGO API and trying to display the map (code written in python) in the form of table (using HTML).

## **views.py**

```
def default_map(request):
    world= folium.Map(
    location=[33.5969, 73.0528],
    zoom_start=2)
    context={'Map':world}
    return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

## **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',  views.home, name='home'),
    path('about',  views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact',  views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('', views.home, name="default"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

## **home.html**

```
 <td colspan="=5", rowspan="15">
             {{Map}}
           </td>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django and Folium integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50517620/django-and-folium-integration)

Answer (score 0):

Why is the context line commented?
You're passing context, but context should be defined.

Comment: faced the same problem after correction

Comment: It would be helpful to include the context. Any errors you see in the javascript console or anywhere else.